# Is it possible to use an Authsub token with Youtube Data API v3?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to access the Youtube Data API v3 with an old AuthSub Youtube Token (Scope=http://gdata.youtube.com) but it always return me this exception :

```
(403) Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.
```

For information, i'm working with the Php client lib.

I really need to access to the api through this token, is it possible?

Comment: What do you not understand about the error message?

Comment: Nothing, it works like a charm with an Oauth 2 token but not with the Authsub token

Comment: No, this isn't possible. the data API v3 is accessible via oauth2 authorization only. However, many parts of the v3 API don't need authorization at all, but just an API key; what data are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: I'm trying to upload a video. I guess i have to update my old tokens.

Comment: With the Data API v3, you won't be able to use AuthSub tokens; rather, authorization to upload is based on oAuth2, so you'll have to code your app to ask the users to authenticate and grant you access, then use the temporary access tokens to authorize the uploads. You can also store their refresh tokens so as to be able to get new access tokens when needed.